# retrofit Request multiple times when upload a list of big pictures

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I use retrofit to upload pictures. When the pictures are small it works well, but when I pick a list of big pictures, the request gets executed more times than expected.

For example, if I choose 9 big pictures, it should execute the upload request 9 times, but it executes a number of times like at times 14 pictures are uploaded.I found some picture are uploaded twice,I wonder if it's because of the reconnection mechanism of okhttp

```
 private void saveToServer() {

    List<Call<MediaResponse>> calls = generateCallList();

    Log.e("", "calls-->" + calls.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < calls.size(); i++) {
        Call<MediaResponse> call = calls.get(i);
        Log.e("", "call**");
        call.enqueue(new Callback<MediaResponse>() {

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MediaResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MediaResponse> call,
                    Response<MediaResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    // TODO 合并刷新列表
                    Log.e("", "response-->" + response.body());
                }
            }
        });
    }

}

private List<Call<MediaResponse>> generateCallList() {
    GuoRetrofit retrofit = new GuoRetrofit();
    AddSingleMediaService service = retrofit.getAddSingleMediaService();
    List<Call<MediaResponse>> calls = new ArrayList<Call<MediaResponse>>();
    for (String path : ImageListAdapter.mSelectedImage) {
        Call<MediaResponse> call = service.addSingleMedia(getMeta(path),
                getfile(path));
        calls.add(call);
    }
    return calls;
}`
```

when i choose 5 pictures, the log is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xm98q.png)

*05-05 15:56:32.238: E/(16416): path-->/system/media/Pre-loaded/Pictures/Picture_01.jpg
05-05 15:56:32.248: E/(16416): path-->/system/media/Pre-loaded/Pictures/Picture_02.jpg
05-05 15:56:32.248: E/(16416): path-->/system/media/Pre-loaded/Pictures/Picture_03.jpg
05-05 15:56:32.258: E/(16416): path-->/system/media/Pre-loaded/Pictures/Picture_04.jpg
05-05 15:56:32.258: E/(16416): path-->/system/media/Pre-loaded/Pictures/Picture_05.jpg
05-05 15:56:32.258: E/(16416): calls-->5

05-05 15:56:32.258: E/(16416): call**retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall@c6c242a

05-05 15:56:32.258: E/(16416): call**retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall@308c2fb8

05-05 15:56:32.258: E/(16416): call**retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall@348058f6

05-05 15:56:32.258: E/(16416): call**retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall@9b08f64

05-05 15:56:32.268: E/(16416): call**retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall@2dfaf993*

Comment: Can you add your logcat output also to the question?

Comment: thanks for your answer,i had added the logcat to the question